# Windows 10 fc command : Comma separated file comparison

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe, diff

I have two file's with 3 GB each to do a comparison and store the difference data into third file.

Following is the sample data.

**File 1**: June_01_2018.csv

[image]

**File 2**: June_02_2018.csv

[image]

**Note**: I want to store the difference into the third file with the column headers.

**Expected Result**: The third file should contain the records from `ID` 11 to 15 with the column headers.

**My try**: `fc` command in command prompt,

```
>fc June_01_2018.csv June_02_2018.csv > June_Diff.csv
```

But getting unexpected result:

[image]

Comment: Related: [How to compare two csv files in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33523362).
`fc` is an interactive command line tool, i.e. it will always produce human readable output. Additionally, it compares text files line by line and doesn't know about the meaning of the lines. In your case, the first line containing the column headers is identical in both files, so it isn't printed. If you read the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fc), you will see that your output is the expected output. I doubt `fc` is the right tool for this task.

Answer (score 1):

Hopes have nothing to do with (realistic) expectations.

The header is exactly the same, so could never be a difference.
Also the excel representation is **not** the csv file, you should post the original files as text.

The following batch file reads in the header and echoes to the diff.
Instead of fc it uses findstr with options

```
/B compare from line begin
/E compare upto line end
/V output lines **not** present in compared file
/G: get strings from a file
```

---

```
@Echo off
Set "File1=June_01_2018.csv"
Set "File2=June_02_2018.csv"
Set "File3=June_Diff.csv"

Set /P "Header="<"%File1%"
( Echo=%Header%
  Findstr.exe /BEV /G:"%File2%" "%File1%"
)>"%File3%"
```

Variant with fc

```
@Echo off
Set "File1=June_01_2018.csv"
Set "File2=June_02_2018.csv"
Set "File3=June_Diff.csv"

Set /P "Header="<"%File1%"
( Echo=%Header%
  fc "%File1%" "%File2%"|more +3 
)>"%File3%"
```

That leaves only the trailing line.

Comment: Getting an error `FINDSTR: Search string too long`.

Comment: What file sizes are you dealing with?

Comment: File is of 3 GB each.

Comment: Well that definetly exceeds [findstr limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman) You can use the Header approach, append the fc variant and tweak the output by removing the unwanted lines starting with `comparing` and `*****`

Comment: I tried with fc command with your code. But getting error RESYNC FAILED. To overcome with this I just added /Lb 200000 to fc because of the difference between two files comes with around 1 millions more or less records. The script is still running from last 15 min..

Comment: So it's not just that the new file has appended entries, they appear also in the middle of the file?

Comment: Yeah! And it has two unique columns.

Comment: Then I fear a text file based diff approach isn't the best method, you might need a dbms.

Comment: Okay, will try from dbms side.